# Do we say "I'm at the optician's"?

Tags: vocabulary

You've come to visit the optician / the eye doctor and he's performing an eye test to evaluate your eye sight / sight.

So at that moment do we say "I'm at the optician's"?, similarly to constructions such as "I'm at the dentist's or hairdresser's

Also, can you let me know if the alternatives after the forward slashes in the first sentence are in fact perfect equivalents?

Comment: It's OK to do what you ask (say or write 'I'm at the optician's') but you should note that in many places (including the UK where I live) a person at a glasses shop who tests your eyes and issues a prescription is not usually an 'eye doctor'.

Comment: And it's fine to say "sight" not "eye sight" if that's what you mean by your second slash. (If not, please clarify.)

Comment: And _eyesight_ is one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you surmise, it's fine to say "I'm at the optician's".

In AmE, "eye doctor" is sometimes used, but it's vague. (It's also technically inaccurate for opticians, who don't typically have doctoral degrees.) We therefore often specify "optician", "optometrist", or "ophthalmologist".

You could shorten "eye sight" to "sight" and you would be understood, but in this context "vision" would be more common.